# Linker .map file browser for AVR-GCC

Tags: c, programming, microcontroller

I am looking for a linker map file browser / analyzer, like http://www.sikorskiy.net/prj/amap/ but able to work with AVR-GCC (avr-ld) linker map files.

I am currently doing `avr-nm -l --size-sort myproject.elf`, after reading eleven years old [avrfreaks post](https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/map-file-analysis-tool?page=all)

```
data           0x0000000000800100        0x2 load address 0x0000000000000110
               0x0000000000800100                PROVIDE (__data_start, .)
*(.data)
*(.data*)
.data.bar      0x0000000000800100        0x2 build/default/production/mainprog.o
               0x0000000000800100                bar
*(.gnu.linkonce.d*)
*(.rodata)
*(.rodata*)
*(.gnu.linkonce.r*)
               0x0000000000800102                . = ALIGN (0x2)
               0x0000000000800102                _edata = .
               0x0000000000800102                PROVIDE (__data_end, .)

bss            0x0000000000800102        0x2
               0x0000000000800102                PROVIDE (__bss_start, .)
*(.bss)
*(.bss*)
*(COMMON)
COMMON         0x0000000000800102        0x2 build/default/production/mainprog.o
               0x0000000000800102                foo
               0x0000000000800104                PROVIDE (__bss_end, .)
               0x0000000000000110                __data_load_start = LOADADDR (.data)
               0x0000000000000112                __data_load_end = (__data_load_start + SIZEOF (.data))
```

[image: sikorskiy.net AMAP]